# How can I automate web UI tests using webdriver+headless chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I came accross this

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

as an alternative to PhantomJS. I would like to write selenium webdriver tests and run them on headless chrome.

Does anyone know of a good documentation to get me started? If not, please share your notes/experiences.

Answer (score 0):

The headless alternatives using Selenium Webdriver are:

- HtmlUnit
- PhantomJS

If you want to use Chrome as browser in a headless way you can use XVFB  (X11 virtual frame buffer).

A recent book about that is "Selenium WebDriver: From Foundations To Framework" by Alex Collins and Yujun Liang. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/selenium-webdriver-book/manuscript/blob/master/manuscript/ch11_drivers.adoc).